# jquery textarea resizer not in POST?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using TextArea Resizer to allow the sizing of a textarea (similar to stackoverflow) found at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TextAreaResizer.

It works for the end user.  However, when I submit the form, the textarea is no where to be found within the POST array.  Why is that?  As soon as I change the class name and submit the form, the POST value is there.  Weird.  Any ideas?

```
<textarea class="resizable" name="ingredients"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is being renamed? Do a **var_dump($_POST);** and see what you are actually posting.

Comment: Strange.  It totally disappears.  I tried previously doing that with no luck.  It is as if the textarea is not within the form.

Comment: The plugin may be removing the textarea element and then adding it back to the page, but maybe not back to the form itself. Try validating your HTML to make sure it is not getting confused by your page structure. Other than that, you may have to move it back into the form with an appendChild. If all of this fails, try contacting the plugin author, as there may be a bug.

Comment: Sounds like a plan.  Thank you for your input.